valueerror in Nbeats model from keras-beats
I am trying to implement NBeats model from keras-beats for timeseries prediction forcasting and it shows me valueerror about using float data type. I tried using astype to convert data to float 32 and 64 and it still showed me similar error
code:
from kerasbeats import prep_time_series, NBeatsModel

# import the dataset

df = pd.read_csv('DailyDelhiClimateTrain.csv', parse_dates = \['date'\], index_col = 'date')

# sort by dates

df.sort_index(inplace = True)

# prep a univariate time series for N-Beats

X, y = prep_time_series(df\['meantemp'\], lookback = 7, horizon = 1)

# create training and test sets

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,

shuffle = False, test_size = 0.2)

# initialize N-Beats and fit

nbeats = NBeatsModel(model_type = 'generic', lookback = 7, horizon = 1)

nbeats.fit(X,y)

Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[104], line 4
      1 X = X.astype('float64')
      2 y = y.astype('float64')
----> 4 nbeats.fit(X,y)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\kerasbeats\nbeats.py:384, in NBeatsModel.fit(self, X, y, **kwargs)
    382 """Build and fit model"""
    383 self.build_layer()
--> 384 self.build_model()
    385 self.model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(self.learning_rate), 
    386                    loss      = [self.loss],
    387                    metrics   = ['mae', 'mape'])
    388 self.model.fit(X, y, batch_size = self.batch_size, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\kerasbeats\nbeats.py:376, in NBeatsModel.build_model(self)
    374 def build_model(self):
    375     """Creates keras model to use for fitting"""
--> 376     inputs     = keras.layers.Input(shape = (self.horizon * self.lookback, ), dtype = 'float')
    377     forecasts  = self.model_layer(inputs)
    378     self.model = Model(inputs, forecasts)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\layers\core\input_layer.py:143, in Input(shape, batch_size, dtype, sparse, batch_shape, name, tensor)
     89 @keras_export(["keras.layers.Input", "keras.Input"])
     90 def Input(
     91     shape=None,
   (...)
     97     tensor=None,
     98 ):
     99     """Used to instantiate a Keras tensor.
    100 
    101     A Keras tensor is a symbolic tensor-like object, which we augment with
   (...)
    141     ```
    142     """
--> 143     layer = InputLayer(
    144         shape=shape,
    145         batch_size=batch_size,
    146         dtype=dtype,
    147         sparse=sparse,
    148         batch_shape=batch_shape,
    149         name=name,
    150         input_tensor=tensor,
    151     )
    152     return layer.output

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\layers\core\input_layer.py:49, in InputLayer.__init__(self, shape, batch_size, dtype, sparse, batch_shape, input_tensor, name, **kwargs)
     47     batch_shape = (batch_size,) + shape
     48 self.batch_shape = tuple(batch_shape)
---> 49 self._dtype = backend.standardize_dtype(dtype)
     51 self.sparse = bool(sparse)
     52 if self.sparse and not backend.SUPPORTS_SPARSE_TENSORS:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\backend\common\variables.py:521, in standardize_dtype(dtype)
    518     dtype = dtype.__name__
    520 if dtype not in dtypes.ALLOWED_DTYPES:
--> 521     raise ValueError(f"Invalid dtype: {dtype}")
    522 return dtype

ValueError: Invalid dtype: float

I tried changing dtype to float 32 and 64 and it still didnt work. I was just expecting model to fit the data. For data I have used climate change daata available at kaggle

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This setup is actually working fine with Python 3.8. This specific issue when using Python 3.11 seems to be caused by keras update and subsequent change in its backend, that added dtype standardization in construction of InputLayer object:
    self._dtype = backend.standardize_dtype(dtype)

This function, as you may have noticed, only allows a specific set of dtype's, namely:
ALLOWED_DTYPES = (
    "float16",
    "float32",
    "float64",
    ... (irrelevant omitted)
)

rendering kerasbeats' code for building the model incompatible with keras, as it uses the plain float data type:
    inputs     = keras.layers.Input(shape = (self.horizon * self.lookback, ), dtype = 'float')

You were right in your attempt to change the data type to float32. You probably just forgot to reload the imported module in your Jupyter Notebook, etc.
Changing the dtype to np.float32 (in <interpreter-path>/site-packages/kerasbeats/nbeats.py: NBeatsModel.build_model(self)) would fix the issue :
    inputs     = keras.layers.Input(shape = (self.horizon * self.lookback, ), dtype = np.float32)

Again, if using Jupyter, don't forget to reload the kerasbeats module.
